# How do I position my Table ? -Word 2013

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-word

How can I position my Table according to my desired one?

As you can see in screenshot, when I hover over top-left corner of table, it shows `+` button to add more rows. Not the icon to change position for a table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can position your table as follows:

> 1. Right click your table or the plus in the top left corner of the table.
> 2. Go to the table properties.
> 3. In the first tab (named Table), at the bottom right there is a button "Positioning..." above the options button.
> 4. Here you can basically adjust it the way you want and you can also cross out the "move with text" feature.

Instead of making a simple button that you also have for pictures, for tables you just have to search a bit further but it is kind of the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for a option to align the table according to the MS word margin size. It does not have any option like 'Move', but using "AutoFit" option the tables can be aligned to fix at window size or content size. Try the below options and check the outcome.

Select the tables > right click and choose 'AutoFit' > select "AutoFit to Contents" or "AutoFit to Windows" or "Fixed Colomn Width" according to your need.

Hope this helps.